# How to disable previous dates in DateTimeRangePicker?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using f_datetimerangepicker library for selecting date range. I want to disable previous dates. How to do it if we are using this library?

```
    DateTimeRangePicker(
                        startText: "From",
                        endText: "To",
                        doneText: "Confirm",
                        cancelText: "Cancel",
                        interval: 5,
                        minimumTime: DateTime.now(),
                        initialStartTime: DateTime.now(),
                        initialEndTime: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)),
                        mode: DateTimeRangePickerMode.date,
                        use24hFormat: false,
                        onConfirm: (start, end) {
                          print(start);
                          print(end);
                        }).showPicker(context);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set date **initialStartTime** to disable previous dates,
like i set there current date,

```
DateTimeRangePicker(
          startText: "From",
          endText: "To",
          doneText: "Yes",
          cancelText: "Cancel",
          interval: 5,
          initialStartTime: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day),
          initialEndTime: now.add(Duration(days: 20)),
          mode: DateTimeRangePickerMode.dateAndTime,
          minimumTime: now.subtract(Duration(days: 5)),
          maximumTime: now.add(Duration(days: 25)),
          onConfirm: (start, end) {
            print(start);
            print(end);
          }).showPicker(context);
```

Comment: That is not working, I've to totally disable the previous dates from the current time. The solution which you gave is only setting the current time.